# Convert Date yyyy/mm/dd to MM dd yyyy

Tags: javascript

I have date yyyy/mm/dd format in JavaScript and I want to display it in textbox by this 
format example: January 1 2014.

```
function displayinTextbox(){
          var datetodisplay = new Date('2014/01/01'); //i want to convert it first in this format (January 1 2014)
          var convertedDate = ///how??????
          document.getElementById('date').value = convertedDate ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` object provides [various methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to access the different parts that make the date/time data.

In your case displaying the month as a name instead of a number will require mapping the month values (from 0 to 11) to the month name (from "January" to "December").

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var convertedDate = monthNames[dateToDisplay.getMonth()] + " " + dateToDisplay.getDate() + " " + "dateToDisplay.getFullYear();
```

If you have to deal with multiple languages and "pretty" formats, you may want to have a look at a formatting library such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 2):

```
function displayinTextbox(){
    var datetodisplay = new Date('2014/01/01');
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var convertedDate = months[datetodisplay.getMonth()] + " " + datetodisplay.getDate() + " "+datetodisplay.getUTCFullYear();
    document.getElementById('date').value = convertedDate ;
}
```

Comment: just copy and paste this function!

Comment: This issue has been solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/3364187)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function displayinTextbox(){
    var datetodisplay = new Date('2014/01/01');
    var convertedDate = datetodisplay.toDateString();
    document.getElementById('date').value = convertedDate ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getDate(): Returns the day of the month.
getDay(): Returns the day of the week. The week begins with Sunday (0 - 6).
getFullYear(): Returns the four-digit year.
getMonth(): Returns the month.
getYear(): Returns the two-digit year.
getUTCDate(): Returns the day of the month according to the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
getUTCMonth(): Returns the month according to the UTC (0 - 11).
getUTCFullYear(): Returns the four-digit year according to the UTC.
```

[Read this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manipulate-time-and-date-values-with-javascripts-date-object/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library.

What you need can be simply done with Moment.js.

```
var str = '2014/01/01';
var formatted = moment(str, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format('MMMM D YYYY');
console.log(formatted);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/949vkvjk/2/