# React html date picker change date label

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vuejs2

[image]

When I capture the selected date to a variable it displays like this "YYYY-MM-DD"
But in the HTML date picker "MM/DD/YYYY"

All I want is to change that label to "YYYY-MM-DD" from "MM/DD/YYYY". I hope there should be a way to do this in JS with React instead of using another date picker library. How do I do this in React?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-ti2p95)

**Updated**
HTML date picker (input type date) display date label like this "MM/DD/YYYY" I do want to change it to display like "YYYY-MM-DD" in the input element

Comment: is the sandbox correct

Comment: anyway something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68555767/13583510

Comment: i didn't understand the problem. which datepicker u r using?

Comment: @cmgchess Sorry I update the correct link

Comment: @NegiRox I use native html element input type = date

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:vuejs2]?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

```
<div className="flex flex-col items-start max-w-sm">
  <label>A single "datetime" input</label>
  <DatePicker defaultValue={new Date()} includeTime />
  <br />

  <label>Paired picker and dropdown</label>
  <div className="flex space-x-2 w-full">
    <DatePicker
      defaultValue={new Date()}
      className="w-3/5"
    />
    <DropdownList
      data={getTimeList()}
      textField="label"
      className="w-2/5 mt-0"
    />
  </div>
  <br />
  <label>Paired picker and experimental time input</label>
  <div className="flex space-x-2 w-full">
    <DatePicker
      defaultValue={new Date()}
      className="w-3/5"
    />
    <TimeInput
      defaultValue={new Date()}
      className="w-2/5 mt-0"
      use12HourClock
    />
  </div>
</div>;
```